# php laravel livewire tab content

Tags: php, laravel

tab content is not working. I select one of `TH` options but it does not change content below. This is my html section:

```
<div class="category-tab">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      @foreach ($categories as $key=>$category)
        <li class="{{ $key == 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">
          <a href="#category_{{$category->id}}" data-toggle="tab"> 
            {{$category->name}}
          </a>
        </li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    @foreach ($categories as $key=>$category)
      <div class=" tab-pan fade {{ $key == 0 ? 'active in' : ''}}" 
           id="#category_{{$category->id}}">
        @php
          $c_products = DB::table('products')-> 
            where('category_id',$category->id)-> 
            get()->take($no_of_products);
        @endphp
        @foreach ($c_products as $c_product)
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
              <div class="single-products">
                <div class="productinfo text-center">
                  <img src="{{asset('assets/images/products')}}/{{$c_product->image}}" 
                       alt="{{$c_product->name}}" />
                  <h2>${{$c_product->regular_price}}</h2>
                  <p>{{$c_product->name}}</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    Add to cart
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        @endforeach
      </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my livewire controller file.

I don't understand what the problem is here.

```
<?php
  namespace App\Http\Livewire;
  use App\Models\Category;
  use App\Models\HomeCategory;
  use Livewire\Component;

  class HomeComponent extends Component
  {
    public function render()
    {
      $category = HomeCategory::find(1);
      $cats=explode(',',$category->sel_categories);
      $categories = Category::whereIn('id',$cats)->get();
      $no_of_products=$category->no_of_products;
      return view('livewire.home-component'
                   ['categories'=>$categories,
                    'no_of_products'=>$no_of_products])->
                   layout('layouts.base');
    }
  }
```

Please guide me where the problem is.

Comment: kindly please help me about this?

Answer (score 2):

finally, I find the answer of the above question actually problem in the following line of code

```
id="#category_{{$category->id}}">
```

remove the '#' from the above line and write it as

```
id="category_{{$category->id}}">
```

that is the right way for execution.